# Spivak Calculus chapter 1, problem 1v

Tags: calculus, factoring

this is my first question here. I am self-studying Spivak's Calculus Fourth Edition and am stuck on Chapter 1 Problem 1v.

The question is to prove that: $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

So I expand the right side out to:

$x(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})-[y(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})]$

Which led me to:

$x^n + x^{n-1}y+...+x^2y^{n-2}+xy^{n-1}-(x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2+...+xy^{n-1}+y^n)$

I can now cancel out so that I end up with:
$x^n+x^2y^{n-2}-x^{n-2}y^2-y^n$

So the question is, how do I get rid of those two remaining components? I'm assuming it had something to do with the expansion '...' but am not sure how to go about it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are making a mistake in cancelling : All the middle terms, including $x^2y^{n-2}$ and $x^{n-2}y^2$ cancel.

Comment: Ok thanks, what exactly are the extra terms in the '...' expansion in this case? It has been some time since I did any factorisation so I can't remember how they map out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing Prahlad's answer in similar notation to your question, with a few more terms explicit,

$x(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+...+x^2y^{n-3}+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})-[y(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+...+x^2y^{n-3}+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})]$

Which leads to:

$x^n + x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2...+x^2y^{n-2}+xy^{n-1}-(x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2+...+x^2y^{n-2}+xy^{n-1}+y^n)$

You can now cancel and end up with:
$x^n-y^n.$

Answer (score 2):

Just write
$$
(x-y)\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}y^k\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-k}y^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}y^{k+1}
$$
$$
= x^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^{n-k}y^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}x^{n-1-k}y^{k+1} - y^n
$$
Re-arranging the indices,
$$
= x^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}x^{n-1-k}y^{k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}x^{n-1-k}y^{k+1} - y^n
$$
$$
= x^n - y^n
$$